# flutter) The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0

Tags: ios, flutter

Debuging the ios simulator outputs the following error.

```
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99.
```

And the Podfile of ios is as follows.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0' #9.0 -> 10.0 edit

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET of ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pdxproj is 9.0.

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 9.0;
```

This project has been going well until recently. However, there is this error all of a sudden.

May I know how to solve this problem?

It's frustrating that I can't do it all of a sudden.

Comment: Check out this https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings Make sure iOS Deployment Target is set to 9.0